# why i am not able to execute 2 nd function i.e. going_first_page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import HtmlTestRunner

class Environment(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\\automation\\chromedriver.exe")

    # login 
    def test_login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("http://localhost/dashboatd")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('uemail').send_keys('xyz@gmail.com')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys('1234567890')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # login page 

    def going_first_page(self):
        going_first_page = self.find_element_by_class_name('color7')
        self.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", going_first_page)
        new_notification = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('fa-paper-plane')
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", new_notification)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='F:\\automation\\reports'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per python guidelines-
"A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests."

So, you should rename it to test_going_first_page(self) from going_first_page(self)

Comment: I have done this it is executed properly  but the  test_going_first_page is executed first insted of test_login

Comment: Yes, it will. Because it executes in a alphabetical order. So it means that test_going_first_page(self) will come first because 'G' in going comes first than L in test_login()

Comment: hi I have understood but I have one more question how I can execute both the test cases in the same window actually what's happening now after executing the first function then windows closed then the second function is executing